# How can I check sensor values with Arduino through a web page?

Tags: networking, web, arduino, monitoring

I am looking for a way to check sensor values (e.g. temperature sensor) with Arduino through a web page.

Checking the sensor values on a web page is more convenient especially when user is at a remote site.

But Arduino doesn't have a network function.

How can I check the sensor values through a web page?

Comment: You need to get the data off the arduino and to a webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use arduino ethernet/Wifi shield, and need to make a webserver.

I know a shield that already has web application embedded in the shield(Web Serial Monitor), called PHPoC Shield for Arduino.

PHPoC Shield provides the same function of Serial Monitor via web.

I was able to check sensor values at anytime without connecting Arduino to the PC because of its web-based function.

Here is the link about Web Serial Monitor of PHPoC Arduino shield

http://www.phpoc.com/support/manual/p4s-348_user_manual/contents.php?id=first_use

Answer (score 3):

A good solution if you're looking for an end user compatible product, is as follows:

Arduino Serial -> PC Software reading Serial port -> Web API to receive data from the PC into a web database-> Web site to display the received data.

This represents a 'loosely coupled' architecture. Allowing each part in the system to focus on one job and do it well.

Here's a picture:
[image: High Level Process Diagram]

You could theoretically install an Ethernet shield directly onto the Arduino, and open it up to the public internet.. but this opens a world of security concerns you really don't want to have to try and solve.

Answer (score 2):

Your IoT Device (Arduino) is on its own soilo and you'd need to have a Network Adaptor/Device on it to communicate with the Internet. You can use a Eathernet Shield or a WiFi Sheield for this purpose.

If you have a Public IP then we can come with a more direct solution, but most of the end users would NOT be having that so you'll need a common connection point on the Internet to share data.

If you just want to read values from the internet you can quickly setup a Twitter account and implement some code to send the sensor values to Twitter channel periodically, where you can read the values from Twitter from anywhere.

See a more detailed description on How to Tweet from Ardunio http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-tweet-from-an-Arduino-using-the-wifi-sheild/